# Screenrecord not working in Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, screen-recording

Just upgraded the Nexus 5 device from Android Lollipop to Marshmallow.
I am trying to record application navigation using recording feature of Android Studio as well as using command line adb shell command.

Both ways are showing error that file(video file that needs to be created) is not accessible or readonly.

I am unable to record anything. Error occurs as soon as I click RECORD or press enter to start recording.

Is there any option in 6.0 that I need to enable?

Command line :

```
Abhinavs-MacBook-Pro:platform-tools abhinavtyagi$ ./adb shell screenrecord /test.mp4
Unable to open '/test.mp4': Read-only file system
```

Android Studio :
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try putting the recording file in the root directory - put it somewhere in the file system that is writable

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, but what about Studio?

Comment: I was very surprised to discover screenrecord, I had been trying various apps from the store to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Android Studio, open Android Monitor from the bottom bar and select the Video icon. You can change parameters such as screen size or rate. When you stop recording you are asked to save it on your computer.